# Which test fits the best here? (oncogenic signalling pathways)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, fishers-exact-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, medicine

I have a list of patients in rows and oncogenic signalling pathways in columns of two independent matrices

One for responders to a drug

one for non-responders to the same drugs

If a patient gets mutation in pathway X we give that 1 otherwise 0

I want to know if pathway X is significantly altered between two groups

I have tried 3 things

```
wilcox.test(group1$pathwayX, group2$pathwayX)
t.test(group1$pathwayX, group2$pathwayX)
fisher.test(x = matrix(
  c(
    group1_sample_size,
    pathwayX_mutated_samples,
    group2_sample_size,
    pathwayX_mutated_samples
  ),
  nrow = 2
)
```

)

Basically I have two boolean matrices for each group

And I am not sure using which statistical test I can say which pathway is significantly altered between two groups

My matrices look like this

```
> dput(group1)
structure(list(Patients = c("1wSYmiuGzvofpfOc.vep.txt_1", "1XqEovQ3rURyS484.vep.txt_1", 
"4LVYCdsQtYjPtJ30.vep.txt_1", "4Psp3OZJbxhm7eyi.vep.txt_1", "7eyiaAprbwfQ5kPa.vep.txt_1", 
"aPbIONzUeWGcIyYx.vep.txt_1", "CdsQtYjPtJ30deI1.vep.txt_1", "ChVkSH31lKuEpIlt.vep.txt_1", 
"Dw7gtgWhjohDwtVG.vep.txt_1", "dxhRH7mCrsZU39G8.vep.txt_1", "ecKEzoTVnJNxoijw.vep.txt_1", 
"hiwgJvkWdxhRH7mC.vep.txt_1", "iwgJvkWdxhRH7mCr.vep.txt_1", "JFc0QILAAMvog6JI.vep.txt_1", 
"M2p1x5z56nffDw7g.vep.txt_1", "r8m244SuOFhqgawP.vep.txt_1", "rKRbXg9sAfx5XMx8.vep.txt_1", 
"seBGMXR0ypMJRNZ7.vep.txt_1", "SKsnsuD9my3Monah.vep.txt_1", "X6mBq2k2pJ07trvD.vep.txt_1", 
"XqEovQ3rURyS484P.vep.txt_1", "ZyduXLr8m244SuOF.vep.txt_1"), 
    BER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CPF = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), CR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CS = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), HR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), MMR = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
    ), OD = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), p53 = c(1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), TLS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), TM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), UR = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), DR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AM = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NHEJ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
>

> dput(group2)
structure(list(Patients = c("2SKsnsuD9my3Mona.vep.txt_1", "4Pyv3CFxV1xnub78.vep.txt_1", 
"8X6mBq2k2pJ07trv.vep.txt_1", "aoZMTHJebqIv4XPB.vep.txt_1", "eI178OJnaJgJiChV.vep.txt_1", 
"iwyHwDFnhwBqHpiY.vep.txt_1", "LVYCdsQtYjPtJ30d.vep.txt_1", "MK8h6Uxg5STxmlmN.vep.txt_1", 
"my3MonahnRNHQhbN.vep.txt_1", "N9GNhyyCA4Psp3OZ.vep.txt_1", "nElUB6DzV88gyC1w.vep.txt_1", 
"NhCGkrdpoVpprdse.vep.txt_1", "prbwfQ5kPa4ecKEz.vep.txt_1", "q2k2pJ07trvDG9H9.vep.txt_1", 
"QET6cz3jXOC7SlKu.vep.txt_1", "Shf9VbopNhCGkrdp.vep.txt_1", "sUaOlXVV1yR708qY.vep.txt_1", 
"U39G8Uh315OvccWS.vep.txt_1", "u8NXDOCcDVQ1HVvt.vep.txt_1", "UaOlXVV1yR708qY8.vep.txt_1", 
"ub78GwNVpYlhZVTC.vep.txt_1", "uqQ4GGWJZrq7U17D.vep.txt_1", "WGcIyYxkF73l0q6q.vep.txt_1", 
"x8X6mBq2k2pJ07tr.vep.txt_1", "yv3CFxV1xnub78Gw.vep.txt_1", "Zo86ZDGWbxqVImri.vep.txt_1"
), BER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CPF = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), CS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), FA = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HR = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), MMR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), NHEJ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), OD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), p53 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), TLS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TM = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), UR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DR = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I am seeing this correctly, but it looks like you have several binary (or at least categorical level) predictor variables and one categorical level outcome variable (the pathway 0/1)..

If this above about your design is correct, you can use **loglinear analysis** to test for significance.

I hope this helps!